# Why comparison won't work properly when one of the value is 1000?

Tags: python, for-loop, comparison-operators

When inserting input b1 as 300, b2 as 1000
Why does the output of this code show "b1>b2"

While b2 is any number lower than 1000 gives the correct output "b2>b1"

Assign b1&b2 a value without using the input function won't cause this problem

```
b1 = input("Enter balance 1: ")
b2 = input("Enter balance 2: ")

list = [739,324,45]



def calculate_balance():
    if b1>b2:
        bl = int(b1)
        bs = int(b2)
        print("b1>b2")
    elif b1==b2:
        bl = int(b1)
        bs = int(b2)
        print("b1=b2")
    else:
        bl = int(b2)
        bs = int(b1)
        print("b2>b1")

calculate_balance()
```

Comment: You need to convert to integers before you do your comparing.

Comment: You're comparing the values **before** you convert them to `int`s.  Just do `b1 = int(input("Enter balance 1:"))` etc so that they're `int` from the start.

Comment: `input()` returns string values, therefore `b1` and `b2` are strings, and therefore your comparisons are using _alphabetic_ ordering instead of _numeric_ ordering.

Answer (score 1):

When you assign a value to `b1` or `b2` in code, you assign an integer. When you use `input` to enter the value, the value is a string.

It needs to be converted to integer before you compare.

```
b1 = int(input("Enter balance 1: "))
```

or

```
if int(b1)>int(b2):
```

Answer (score 0):

@Pranab is right, you will need to compare when it is an integer. If you don't do that it will calculate them by letters (I think it will work like that)!
The player could input `Hello!` to the screen so, please use `int(input())`, It will work perfectly.